# How to parse deeply nested using LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

How do I parse the following XML using LINQ?
I need to insert into a database table *OrderNumber, ShipAddress, ShipCity, ShipState* for each **Order** & **OrderCancelled**.
Then in a separate table I need to insert *OrderId* from the **Returns/Amount** section.

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OrdersReport Date="2012-08-01">
<Client>
<ClientId>1</ClientId>
  <Orders>
    <Order>
      <OrderNumber>1</OrderNumber>
      <ShipAddress>123 Main St.</ShipAddress>
      <ShipCity>MyCity</ShipCity>
      <ShipState>AZ</ShipState>
    </Order>
    <Order>
      <OrderNumber>2</OrderNumber>
      <ShipAddress>111 Main St.</ShipAddress>
      <ShipCity>OtherCity</ShipCity>
      <ShipState>AL</ShipState>
    </Order>
    <OrderCancelled>
      <OrderNumber>3</OrderNumber>
      <ShipAddress>111 Main St.</ShipAddress>
      <ShipCity>OtherCity</ShipCity>
      <ShipState>AL</ShipState>
    </OrderCancelled>
  </Orders>  
  <Returns>
    <Amount>
      <OrderId>2</OrderId>
      <OrderId>3</OrderId>
    </Amount>
  </Returns> 
</Client>
<Client>
<ClientId>2</ClientId>
<!-- Same Tree structure as Client 1 -->
</Client>
</OrdersReport>
```

Based on the responses I got, I have updated the question.

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(rootFolder + "Generic.xml");
    var query = doc.Descendants("Order")
                   .Concat(doc.Descendants("OrderCancelled"))
                   .Select(x => new
                   {
                       OrderNumber = (int)x.Element("OrderNumber"),
                       ShipAddress = (string)x.Element("ShipAddress"),
                       ShipCity = (string)x.Element("ShipCity"),
                       ShipState = (string)x.Element("ShipState")
                   });           

    var amount = doc.Descendants("Amount")                         
                  .Select(y => new
                  {
                      OrderId = (int)y.Element("OrderId")
                  });

    foreach (var o in query)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(o.OrderNumber + o.ShipAddress + o.ShipCity);
    }
    foreach (var r in amount)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(r.OrderId);
    }
```

The amount enumeration is only giving me the first OrderId, what am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Colors showed up after posting :-) but not still not indenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just want all the descendant Order/OrderCancelled elements:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("file.xml");
var query = doc.Descendants("Order")
               .Concat(doc.Descendants("OrderCancelled"))
               .Select(x => new {
                           OrderNumber = (int) x.Element("OrderNumber"),
                           ShipAddress = (string) x.Element("ShipAddress"),
                           ShipCity = (string) x.Element("ShipCity"),
                           ShipState = (string) x.Element("ShipState")
                       });
```

Then you can iterate over the results, which will be a sequence of the anonymous type, and do whatever you need to insert it into the database.

Comment: So, I could do a similar select for the Returns?

Comment: @Picflight: Absolutely, although note that you've have to get each `OrderId` element within each `Amount`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible without concatenation:

```
var query = from o in xdoc.Descendants("Orders").Elements()
            select new 
            {
                OrderNumber = (int)o.Element("OrderNumber"),
                ShipAddress = (string)o.Element("ShipAddress"),
                ShipCity = (string)o.Element("ShipCity"),
                ShipState = (string)o.Element("ShipState")
            };
```

Comment: How does that satisfy "for each Order & OrderCancelled"?

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry, forgot to do `Elements()`

Comment: Right, that will do it - so long as there are *never* any other elements within `Orders`.